# Swift: How to lazy load a data model from JSON displayed in UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Application that keeps a data structure similar to this:

```
{projectgroups: [
    {project: [
        {id: “10001”,
        name: “Testproject 1”,
        creator: “Joe Doe”,
        duedate: “12/12/15”,
        tasks: [
            {id: “1001”,
            name: “Document 1A”,
            size: “10MB”,
            tasksteps: [
                {id: “11001”,
                name: “Analysis”,
                assignee: “John Doe”,
                due date: “12/11/15”,
                completed: 0},
                {id: “11002”,
                name: “Publish”,
                assignee: “Dave Doe”,
                due date: “12/10/15”,
                completed: 0} ],
            }, 
            {id: “1002”,
            name: “Document 1B”,
            size: “5MB”,
            tasksteps: [
                {id: “21002”,
                name: “Analysis”,
                assignee: “Jane Doe”,
                due date: “12/09/15”,
                completed: 1}
            ]}
        ]},
        {id: “10002”,
        name: “Testproject 2”,
        creator: “Ken Doe”,
        due date: “11/12/15”,
        tasks: [
            {id: “3001”,
            name: “Document 2A”,
            size: “11MB”,
            tasksteps: [
                {id: “33001”,
                name: “Analysis”,
                assignee: “John Doe”,
                due date: “11/09/15”,
                completed: 0}
            ]}
        ]}],
    <…more projects here…>
    }]
}
```

The idea is to represent this data in tableviews to the user:

ViewController 1: List of Projects. Display all projects within the projectgroups array. UITableViewCell would contain the Name of the project, number of tasks, and smallest due date (closest to present date)
￼

ViewController 2: List of Tasks of a Project. Display all tasks within the selected project group. UITableViewCell would contain the name of task, number of task steps, and smallest due date (closest to present date)
￼

ViewController 3: List of Tasksteps of a Task. Display all task steps within the selected task. UITableViewCell would contain the name of task step, and the the due date of the task step.
￼

The key here is that ViewController 1 needs to be aware of all data, not just the projects. The same goes for ViewController 2. This is because displaying the number of tasks, task steps, and the smallest due date requires some querying.

Question 1:
How do I most efficiently keep this data model in my application. I’m thinking a singleton would work well. But how do I set this up in terms of the object classes and methods to retrieve the data, obtain the count of tasks and task steps, and determine the minimum due date?

Question 2:
I’m also considering edit functionality in the ViewControllers, so Due Dates may change when a user is in ViewController 3. Also, the user might add or remove tasks and/or task steps. Once the user moves backward to ViewController 2 or 1, the data needs to be refreshed, reflecting the changes made. How do I best implement a mechanism that let the ViewControllers know that data in child ViewControllers has changed?

Question 3:
The data in this model is actually partially loaded through JSON from a server. There is no web service providing the entire data model as pictured above. There are actually these 3 calls: 
- fetchProjectGroup: Retrieves the entire project group including projects, but no tasks are included. 
- fetchTasksInProjectGroup(project_id): Returns the tasks only for a particular project.
- fetchTaskStepsOfTask(task_id): This call returns the task steps that are associated with a particular task. 
There are also separate calls to edit data and let the server know about changes. My plan to keep integrity is to change data in the singleton directly, and then do an asynchronous call to the server letting the server know the data has changed.

How do I implement a mechanism that lets me load/save the data by making above calls? I’m looking for a solution that lazily loads data (on demand) only when needed. I’m expecting delayed population of values in the UITableViewCell, e.g. in ViewController 1, the label with the project name should be populated right after the first web service call is done, while the task count and smallest Due date label should be separately populated once each of the appropriate calls are completed and data is loaded.

Question 4:
How do I best manage activityIndicators, spinners to show up in the ViewControllers that respond to the ongoing activity, e.g. only show up when a web service call is made.

Comment: How big is the JSON, realistically? 1 MB? 10 MB? 100 MB?

Comment: Hi, the amount of JSON data per call varies between a few hundred KB up to 1 MB. Thank you for your help in advance!